# Reading from a gzipped csv file stored in Google Cloud Storage without downloading file first

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to read the header row from a gzipped csv file stored in Google Cloud Storage without having to download the file first? I would like to be able to do this in Node.js.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, not for compressed archives. If the file is not compressed then you can start reading at any offset.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to avoid downloading the files since they're so large, and all I really need is the file's schema. Do you know if there's a way to download only a small part of the file instead?

Comment: Upload the schema as a separate object?

Comment: Well, I'm not the one doing the uploading; the files are being dropped into a GC Storage bucket by another party, and I want to pull just the schema row from each file.